# app.receivedEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am building a phonegap application and I get the following error message when debugging.

> Uncaught TypeError: app.receivedEvent is not a function(…)** on line 18 of my JS code (I point it out below).

To be honest I have read many guides on the deviceready but I just can't figure out how to properly use it for my phonegap build code.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

  <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Anton|Patua+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fact_page.css">
  <title>One Direction Facts</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>One Direction - Fact of the Day</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="deviceready" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h2 id="todayh2" class="invisible"> Today's One Direction Fact:</h2>
    <div id="quotebox" class="PulseEffect icon">
      <div id="ShineDiv" class="shine"></div>
      <div class="facebox fade icon">
         <div id="ShineDiv2" class=""></div>
      </div>
      <p class="hidden" id="qotd"> Welcome to<br><strong>One Direction Facts.</strong><br><br>You will get a random fact each day.</p>
    </div>
    <a id="nextQ" class="" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">View Fact</a>
    <div class="XPmeter animateXP" >
            <span id="bar" style="width: 20%"></span>
          <div id="medaldiv">
                                            <img id="medal" src="images/medal3.svg"><p id="lvl">1</p>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>New Features Coming Soon!</h1>
  </div>
</div>

 <!--  --------------------JS------------------------ -->
  <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app_scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/admob.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my JS:**

```
    var app = {

    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {

/*--error is here-->*/     app.receivedEvent('deviceready'); 

    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent:
            $("#nextQ").click(function(){ 

        var tempd = new Date(); //Get today's date
        //Checks if localstorage had 'DateOpened' already stored

     // Note that by adding strings in there, we end up with a string instead of adding.
        // Note the order: Year first, then month, then day.
        // Also, since we display it, we put separators in and add 1 to month (since Jan = 0).
        var str = tempd.getFullYear() + "-" + (tempd.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + tempd.getDate();
        console.log("Today's date: " + str);

        var localVal = localStorage.getItem('DateOpened'); 
        console.log("Previous localVal: " + localVal);

        if(localVal != null){
            var difference = localVal.localeCompare(str);
        }
            console.log("localeCompare: " + difference);
        //If stored date is older than this date do something:  
        if(localVal  == null || difference < 0){  
                        // If the localstorage doesn't exist, nothing happens
                        console.log("App will now run once for today.")

        //Run the JS for the app (give new quote since it is a new day)

                                var Quotes = [];
                                var ID = [];
                                var Tag = [];
                                        //Get quotes from JSON file
                                        $.ajax({
                                                            url: './json/facts.json',
                                                            dataType: 'json',
                                                            type: 'get',
                                                            success: function(data){
                                                                    console.log(data);
                                                                    console.log("successfully imported the JSON file");
                                                                    console.log(data.length); //Returns 64
                                                                    totalQ = data.length; 
                                                                    for (i = 0; i < totalQ; i++){
                                                                                    ID[i] = data[i][0];
                                                                                    Tag[i] = data[i][1];
                                                                                    Quotes[i] = data[i][2];
                                                                    }
                                                                console.log(Quotes.length);
                                                    }
                                        })
                                        .done(function(data){ //This waits for AJAX to be done before running

                                                var Quote = new String;
                                                var qnumber = 0;
                                                var totalQ //The total number of available quotes to choose from
                                                var CurrentImage = String;

                                                totalQ = Quotes.length - 1;
                                                console.log("TotalQ = " + totalQ);

                                                //Get list of which facts have already been seen
                                                var seen = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('seen'));
                                             console.log("var seen = " + seen);
                                                    if (seen == null){
                                                            var seen = new Array(totalQ);
                                                         for (var i = 0; i < seen.length; ++i) {
                                                                    seen[i] = false;
                                                            }
                                                         console.log("var seen = " + seen);
                                                    }

                                             //Get a Quote
                                                ChooseQuote(0,totalQ);

                                                //Change the image depending on the quote

                                                //replace the quote with a new one
                                                $("#qotd:visible").hide();
                                                $("#ShineDiv").addClass("shine");
                                                $(".facebox").css("background-image",CurrentImage);
                                                $(".facebox").css("opacity","1.0");
                                                $("#qotd").html(Quote);
                                                console.log("Image Changed");

                                                increaseXP();
                                                //================
                                            function ChooseQuote(min,max){
                                                 //Choose 2 random numbers, one for quotes one for image
                                                    var RandomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
                                                    var ImageNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(5-1+1)+1);

                                                    Quote = Quotes[RandomNum];
                                                    CurrentImage = "url(./images/FaceBoxes/" + Tag[RandomNum] + "/" + Tag[RandomNum] + ImageNum + ".png)";
                                                    if (seen[RandomNum] == true ) {
                                                        //Choose new quote
                                                        ChooseQuote(0,totalQ);
                                                        console.log("Has this fact been seen before? Answer: " + seen[RandomNum] );
                                                        var numOfTrue = 0;
                                                                        for(var i=0; i<=totalQ; i++){
                                                                                        if(seen[i] === "true")
                                                                                                    numOfTrue++;
                                                                        }
                                                            if (numOfTrue = totalQ) {
                                                                             localStorage.setItem('All_Facts_Seen:', true);
                                                                             console.log("All the Facts have been seen. Resetting Facts.");
                                                                             seen = new Array(totalQ); //Empty the seen Array
                                                                             localStorage.setItem('seen', JSON.stringify(seen)); //Save the empty Array
                                                                        }
                                                            }
                                                 else { 
                                                        seen[RandomNum] = "true";
                                                        console.log("This fact has never been seen.")
                                                    }
                                                    console.log(Quote);
                                                    console.log(CurrentImage);

                                                 //Remeber which fact is displayed
                                                 localStorage.setItem('Curr_Fact', Quote);
                                                 localStorage.setItem('Curr_ImgUrl', CurrentImage);
                                                 localStorage.setItem('seen', JSON.stringify(seen));
                                                    }
                                    //==================
                                //Save the current date in local storage
        localStorage.setItem('DateOpened',str);
                             console.log("The App Ran, you can get a new fact tomorrow");
                                console.log("Current LocalStorage Date: " + str);
                                });
        }
     else {
            //If it is still the same day, show the last fact & image
             var Quote = localStorage.getItem('Curr_Fact');
             var CurrentImage = localStorage.getItem('Curr_ImgUrl');

               $("#qotd:visible").hide(); //Hide main quote
               $("#ShineDiv2").addClass("shine");
                        if ($('h2').hasClass("invisible")){ //if heading is invisble show it, remove that class
                            $('h2').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('slow').removeClass("invisible");
                        }
                        $(".facebox").css("background-image",CurrentImage); 
               setTimeout( function() { //This is so that the first image and new image don't crossfade/stretch
                                $(".facebox").css("opacity","1.0");
                                }, 100);

                        $("#qotd").html(Quote); //Replace the main message with the actual quote

                        console.log("Showing the same fact as before. Wait until tomorrow to get a new fact.");
        }
    },
}; 


$(window).load(function() {
var headerh;
var footerh;
var pageh;
var hbtn_nextq;

headerh = $("div[data-role='header']").outerHeight();
footerh = $("div[data-role='footer']").outerHeight();
pageh = $(window).height();

console.log(headerh + " " + footerh + " " + pageh);

var difference = pageh - headerh - footerh;

$(".ui-content").css("height", difference);

var h1, h2, h3, h4 , h5;

h1 = $(".ui-content").outerHeight();
h2 = $(".ui-content>h2").outerHeight();
h3 = $("#quotebox").outerHeight(true);
h4 = $("#nextQ").outerHeight();

h5 = ((h1 - h2 - h3 - h4) /2) - 50;
    console.log(h1);
 console.log(h2);
 console.log(h3);
    console.log(h4);
 console.log(h5);

 var h5s = h5 + "px";

//$("#quotebox").css("margin-top",h5s);
$(".ui-content>h2").css("margin-top",h5s);
//$("#nextQ").css("margin-bottom",h5s);

//ShowXP();
//Make the quotebox flip over on click
$(".facebox, #ShineDiv").click(function(){
    $("#quotebox").removeClass("PulseEffect")
    $("#ShineDiv").removeClass("shine");
    $(".facebox").css("opacity","0");
    $("#qotd").fadeIn("slow", function(){});
});


ShowXP();    

});


function increaseXP(){
    //Get the lvl and xp from storage
    var lvl = localStorage.getItem("lvl", lvl);
    var XP = localStorage.getItem("XP", XP);
    console.log("Old XP = " + XP + " Old Level = " + lvl);

    lvl = parseInt(lvl);
    XP = parseInt(XP);

    //Increase XP
    XP = XP + 25;

    //Increase lvl
    if (XP >= 100){
      lvl = lvl + 1;
      localStorage.setItem('XP',XP);
      localStorage.setItem('lvl',lvl);

      UpdateXP(XP);
        setTimeout(function() {
      ShowUP(lvl);
        }, 200);
      XP = XP - 100;
                     console.log("Current XP = " + XP + " Current Level = " + lvl);
      UpdateXP(XP);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('XP',XP);
    localStorage.setItem('lvl',lvl);
    UpdateXP(XP);

}

function ShowXP(){
    var XP = localStorage.getItem("XP");
    var lvl = localStorage.getItem("lvl");


    if (XP == null){
        XP = 0;
        localStorage.setItem("XP", XP);
    }
    if (lvl == null){
        lvl = 1;
        localStorage.setItem("lvl",lvl);
    }

    lvl = parseInt(lvl);
    XP = parseInt(XP);

    $("#lvl").text(lvl);

    $(".XPmeter > span#bar").each(function() {
      $(this)
        .data("origWidth", XP)
        .width(0)
        .animate({
          width: $(this).data("origWidth") + "%" // or + "%" if fluid
        }, 1200);
    });

}

function UpdateXP(XP){
    $(".XPmeter > span#bar").each(function() {
      $(this)
        .animate({
          width: XP + "%" // or + "%" if fluid
        }, 1200);
    });
}

function ShowUP(new_level){
    $("#medal").animate({height: "100px" },600, function(){
        $("#lvl").text(new_level);
        $("#medal").animate({height: "50px" },600);
    });

    $(".XPmeter > span#bar").width("0");
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------//
//                                                             //
// This is the scirpt that will get the facts and display them //
//                                                             //
//-------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Comment: The return value of `$("#nextQ").click(function(){...})` is not a function

Comment: why does it have to return a function?

Comment: You will have to answer this, but from the code you act like it is a function: `app.receivedEvent('deviceready');`

Comment: doesn't that just say run the code for that event? I got that from the startup guide for making a phonegap app so I'm not really sure how  `app.receivedEvent('deviceready');` works. I've read many guides on it but none seem to be relevant to what I am doing.

Comment: [JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: That's not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `receivedEvent` is not defined as a functions but as a property of the `app` object so it can't be called as a function.

You to change it from:

```
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent:
```

to:

```
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
```